# how to change elements in media queries with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

How can I change elements defined in a media query with javascript?

My intent is to make a hidden element visible with javascript, while this element should only be visible with screen size smaller than 1000px. So once the element is made visible (upon a mouse click) while the screen is smaller than 1000px, the element should be hidden when the user resizes the window afterwards to a size greater than 1000px.

This is the code, with some explanation of the purpose in the code itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    #mobile-only, #mobile-only-after-click { display: none; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
      #mobile-only { display: block;}
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function show () {
      document.getElementById("mobile-only-after-click").style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>In desktop view this is the only visible div</div>
  <div id="mobile-only">In mobile view this div is extra. <a href="#" onclick="show(); return false;">Click</a> to see a third div</div>
  <div id="mobile-only-after-click">This third div should only be visible for mobile users. It should be hidden for desktop users after resizing the window to a larger size, after it was shown in a small screen upon a click.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding the following, but it does not work. The third div is not hidden once shown and after making the window wider than 1000px after that event.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
   #mobile-only-after-click { display: none; } 
}
```

Comment: That's what happens when you change inline styles with javascript, they override the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but with this solution the mobile-only divs are always hidden, even on small screens where they should be visible.

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/pwBvre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 3 potential solutions.

**Solution #1**

We can override the media query with a simple `window.onresize` event watcher, and keep the shown element visible, or hide it when the screen goes over 1000px.

To test this you'll need to hit the <kbd>Expand Snippet</kbd> button to view the code snippet in full screen so you can activate the media query.

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById("mobile-only-after-click").style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');

  window.onresize = function() {
  if (window.innerWidth >= 1000) {
    document.getElementById("mobile-only-after-click").style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mobile-only-after-click").style.display =
 'block';
  }
}
}
```

```css
#mobile-only,
#mobile-only-after-click {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #mobile-only {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>In desktop view this is the only visible div</div>
<div id="mobile-only">In mobile view this div is extra. <a href="#" onclick="show(); return false;">Click</a> to see a third div</div>
<div id="mobile-only-after-click">This third div should only be visible for mobile users. It should be hidden for desktop users after resizing the window to a larger size, after it was shown in a small screen upon a click.</div>
```

**Solution #2**

A better solution might be add a new class to the element, which uses a new media query. In this solution we can forget about a `window.onresize` event watcher and simply add a new `.shown` class to the element which will use a new set of CSS rules to show/hide the element.

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById("mobile-only-after-click").classList.add('shown');
}
```

```css
#mobile-only,
#mobile-only-after-click {
  display: none;
}

#mobile-only-after-click.shown {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #mobile-only {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #mobile-only-after-click.shown {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>In desktop view this is the only visible div</div>
<div id="mobile-only">In mobile view this div is extra. <a href="#" onclick="show(); return false;">Click</a> to see a third div</div>
<div id="mobile-only-after-click">This third div should only be visible for mobile users. It should be hidden for desktop users after resizing the window to a larger size, after it was shown in a small screen upon a click.</div>
```

**Solution #3**

The best solution - if it's possible to alter the HTML you can move the `#mobile-only-after-click` element inside the `#mobile-only` element. This works with no change to your existing JS/CSS.

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById("mobile-only-after-click").style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');

}
```

```css
#mobile-only,
#mobile-only-after-click {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #mobile-only {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>In desktop view this is the only visible div</div>
<div id="mobile-only">In mobile view this div is extra. <a href="#" onclick="show(); return false;">Click</a> to see a third div
  <div id="mobile-only-after-click">This third div should only be visible for mobile users. It should be hidden for desktop users after resizing the window to a larger size, after it was shown in a small screen upon a click.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx Brett! Very helpful.

Comment: Great, glad we could help. And please mark the solution that answered your question as the accepted solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could try some JQuery. 
slideToggle() for showing your third div overall. 
The standard example in the online documentatie should work. 
The visibility of the second and third div can be handled by css.
Or with JQuery again, never used it but you can get the browser width with some method.

Good luck,

B